# Set up HTTPS/SSL Certificate for our website on another server

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, ssl, https, windows-server-2008

I'm pretty new to the https world, so bear with me.

There are 2 web-servers involved:

Webserver1 has been in the organization a few years and is hosting/running multiple websites with https encryption (app1.ourcompany.com, app2.ourcompany.com, etc).  It has a valid, signed certificate.

Webserver2 is a new server, for which I am responsible.  I am tasked with setting up https and getting the certificate, etc.  It has a web app running on it, but it does not have a domain name (only has an IP address)...which as I recently learned, is a requirement for a signed certificate.

What I'd like to know is this -- is it possible to set up a site on Webserver1 that points to the site I'm hosting on Webserver2 (ie SiteOnWebserver2.ourcompany.com) which also utilizes the Webserver1's signed/verified certificate?

Thanks for your time, SO gurus!

--Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regular SSL certificate is valid for only a single domain name (such as `app1.ourcompany.com`).  If this is the type of certificate currently being used then the existing SSL certificates will not work on your new server.  If you did try this you would get an error in the browser saying that the site's domain name doesn't match the name in the SSL certificate.

The other option is to use a wildcard SSL certificate.  These kinds of certificates are assigned to a certain parent domain (like `ourcompany.com`) and will work for all subdomains.  This kind of certificate would work for `app1.ourcompany.com`, `app2.ourcompany.com`, as well as your `SiteOnWebserver2.ourcompany.com`.

Comment: I've verified that WebServer1 has a wildcard certificate.  Does that mean that I can host the application on Webserver2 and utilize the certs on WebServer1?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to install the same certificate from WebServer1 on to WebServer2.